# При получении от трекера пиров, не могу понять как правильно распарсить их хосты и порты

Tags: c#, .net, ip, torrent

В представленном массиве байт, закодированы 3 хоста и порта пира:

```
byte[] byteData =
{
    188, 191, 18,  186, 139, 185,
    46,  98,  170, 16,  240, 46,
    2,   135, 81,  12,  175, 142
};
```

В спецификации `BitTorrent`'a сказано:

> peers: (двоичная модель) Вместо использования словарной модели,
>   описанной выше, значение peers может быть строкой, состоящей из
>   кратных 6 байт. Первые 4 байта являются IP-адресом, а последние 2
>   байта являются номером порта. Все в сетевой (big endian) нотации.
>
> Как упоминалось выше, список пиров по умолчанию имеет длину 50. Если в
>   торренте будет меньше пиров, то список будет меньше. В противном
>   случае трекер случайным образом выбирает пиров для включения в ответ.
>   Трекер может выбрать реализацию более интеллектуального механизма
>   выбора одноранговых узлов при ответе на запрос. Например, можно не
>   сообщать о семенах другим сеялкам.
>
> Клиенты могут отправлять запрос в трекер чаще, чем в указанный
>   интервал, если происходит событие (то есть остановлено или завершено)
>   или если клиенту необходимо узнать о большем количестве пиров. Однако
>   считается плохой практикой «забивать» трекер, чтобы получить несколько
>   пиров. Если клиенту нужен большой список пиров в ответе, он должен
>   указать параметр numwant.

Я попытался конвертировать байты в `long`и `int` значения, но `IPEndPoint`, на основе конвертированных данных получился кривой:

```
byte[] bytes = bString.Value.ToArray();

byte[] hb = new byte[4];
byte[] pb = new byte[2];

uint badHost = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);

Array.Copy(bytes, hb, 4);
Array.Copy(bytes, 4, pb, 0, 2);

Array.Reverse(pb);

hb[0] = (byte)((badHost & 0x000000ff) << 24);
hb[1] = (byte)((badHost & 0x0000ff00) << 8);
hb[2] = (byte)((badHost & 0x00ff0000) >> 8);
hb[3] = (byte)((badHost & 0xff000000) >> 24);

long realHost = (long)hb[0] | hb[1] | hb[2] | hb[3];
int realPort = (pb[0] | pb[1]);

IPEndPoint host = new IPEndPoint(realHost, realPort);
```

Первый хост выглядит вот так: `186.0.0.0:187`, однако, я не верю что у кого то есть такой адрес.

Подскажите как правильно конвертировать полученные данные в хост и порт пиров?

Comment: Раз там упомянуты конкретные байты - то это точно не строка в UTF-8. Можете привести входные данные в виде массива байт?

Comment: Добавил массив.

Comment: ожидаемый результат 188.191.18.186:35769 для первого пира?

Comment: @PashaPash, возможно, но не думаю, т.к. сказано что `Big Endian`, думаю наоборот `186.18.191.188:35769`.

Comment: @PashaPash: Блин, там же только про порт сказано... Вот я не внимательный, вы правы.

Comment: Разве биг индиан это не по порядку в нашем случае? И для ip и для порта

Comment: Big Endian это и есть 188.191.18.186. Более того, второй пир и в данный момент прекрасно принимает подключения на 46.98.170.16:61486

Comment: Так мне что стоит просто захардкодить адрес хоста как строку разделяя запятыми?

Comment: @ヒミコ  все уже захардкожено до нас, там есть родное преобразование :)

Comment: `byte[] byted =
{
    188, 191, 18,  186, 139, 185,
    46,  98,  170, 16,  240, 46,
    2,   135, 81,  12,  175, 142
};
           for (int i=0; i<18;i+=6){
           var bytes = byted.Skip(i).Take(4);
           var portA= byted.Skip(i+4).Take(2).ToArray();
           int port=portA[1]|(portA[0]<<8);
           Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(".",bytes)}:{port}");
           }` С телефона накидал :) но это скорее для себя XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
byte[] byteData =
{
    188, 191, 18,  186, 139, 185,
    46,  98,  170, 16,  240, 46,
    2,   135, 81,  12,  175, 142
};
var address = new IPAddress(byteData.Take(4).ToArray());
var port = (byteData[4] << 8) + byteData[5];
Console.WriteLine(new IPEndPoint(address, port)); // 186.18.191.188:35769
```